# HttpWebRequest with Digest authentication returns error 401 in metro app (windows 8)

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, webrequest, digest

I'm developing an app for Windows 8 (metro app) that needs to download some content from a server that requires Digest authentication.

This is the code I'm using to send the request:

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://my_site_with_http_digest_auth");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
if (webResponse != null && webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // Analyze response here...
}
```

When I run this code in a metro app, the server returns `401 (authentication error)`. The exactly same code runs well on Windows Phone and a normal .NET app. This only happens on Windows 8 metro app. Maybe this is a bug in WinRT. Someone else has experienced this problem in metro apps? Any tip?

Comment: I found that the problem only occurs when the URI contains a query string. Seems to be a bug in the WinRT classes. I'm bypassing it using POST instead of GET, so there is no query string and the hash for Digest are calculated correctly.